# CSS progress bar line not displaying

Tags: html, css

I have created a progress bar that works perfectly fine in codepen. But, inside my website, it acts out! Specifically, the line going through each step does not display properly.

```css
.timeline {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 2.5rem 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  /*     border: 1px solid red; */
}

.step {
  flex: 1 1 14.2%;
  position: relative;
}

.past {
  color: #d0d0d0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*     border: 1px solid red; */
}

.past::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  left: 50%;
  top: 2.2rem;
  z-index: -1;
}

.current {
  color: #d0d0d0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.roadmap-icon {
  padding: 1rem;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 3px 0 #3793b7, 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.roadmap-icon-selected {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 1.2rem;
}

.future {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.future::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  right: 50%;
  top: 2.2rem;
  z-index: -1;
}

.icon-text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="step">
    <div class="past">
      <a href="/project/add">
        <div id="project_id" class="roadmap-icon">
          <svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-building" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M14.763.075A.5.5 0 0 1 15 .5v15a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V14h-1v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V10a.5.5 0 0 1 .342-.474L6 7.64V4.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .276-.447l8-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .487.022zM6 8.694L1 10.36V15h5V8.694zM7 15h2v-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V15h2V1.309l-7 3.5V15z"
            ></path>
            <path
              d="M2 11h1v1H2v-1zm2 0h1v1H4v-1zm-2 2h1v1H2v-1zm2 0h1v1H4v-1zm4-4h1v1H8V9zm2 0h1v1h-1V9zm-2 2h1v1H8v-1zm2 0h1v1h-1v-1zm2-2h1v1h-1V9zm0 2h1v1h-1v-1zM8 7h1v1H8V7zm2 0h1v1h-1V7zm2 0h1v1h-1V7zM8 5h1v1H8V5zm2 0h1v1h-1V5zm2 0h1v1h-1V5zm0-2h1v1h-1V3z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="/project/add" class="icon-text">Step 1</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <div class="past">
      <a href="/project/342/property/add/">
        <div id="land_id" class="roadmap-icon">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="2rem" height="2rem" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-binoculars" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path
              d="M3 2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 4.5 1h1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 7 2.5V5h2V2.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10.5 1h1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13 2.5v2.382a.5.5 0 0 0 .276.447l.895.447A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 15 7.118V14.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 9 14.5v-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .146-.354l.854-.853V9.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v.793l.854.853A.5.5 0 0 1 7 11.5v3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5.5 16h-3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1 14.5V7.118a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 .83-1.342l.894-.447A.5.5 0 0 0 3 4.882V2.5zM4.5 2a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5V3h2v-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1zM6 4H4v.882a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.83 1.342l-.894.447A.5.5 0 0 0 2 7.118V13h4v-1.293l-.854-.853A.5.5 0 0 1 5 10.5v-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6.5 8h3A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11 9.5v1a.5.5 0 0 1-.146.354l-.854.853V13h4V7.118a.5.5 0 0 0-.276-.447l-.895-.447A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 12 4.882V4h-2v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V4zm4-1h2v-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5V3zm4 11h-4v.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V14zm-8 0H2v.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h3a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V14z"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="/project/342/property/add/" class="icon-text">step 2</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <div class="past">
      <a href="/development/proforma/add">
        <div id="proforma_id" class="roadmap-icon">
          <svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-card-checklist" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M14.5 3h-13a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v9a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h13a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5zm-13-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3.5v9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h13a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 14.5 2h-13z"
            ></path>
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M7 5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-1.496-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-.5-.5a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708l.146.147 1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0zM7 9.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-1.496-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-.5-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .708-.708l.146.147 1.146-1.147a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="/project/add" class="icon-text">Step 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <div class="current">
      <div id="development" type_id="" class="roadmap-icon roadmap-icon-selected">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1.5em" height="1.5em" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bag-plus" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path
            fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M8 7.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v1.5H10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H8.5V12a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-1.5H6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h1.5V8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"
          />
          <path
            d="M8 1a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.5 2.5V4h-5v-.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 8 1zm3.5 3v-.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0-7 0V4H1v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h-3.5zM2 5h12v9a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V5z"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>

      <a href="/development/project/step4" class="icon-text">Step 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <div class="future">
      <a href="/development/proforma/139/financing/add">
        <div id="financing_id" class="roadmap-icon">
          <svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-cash-stack" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M14 3H1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12a1 1 0 0 1 1 1h-1z"></path>
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M15 5H1v8h14V5zM1 4a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v8a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h14a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V5a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H1z"
            ></path>
            <path
              d="M13 5a2 2 0 0 0 2 2V5h-2zM3 5a2 2 0 0 1-2 2V5h2zm10 8a2 2 0 0 1 2-2v2h-2zM3 13a2 2 0 0 0-2-2v2h2zm7-4a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="/development/project/step5" class="icon-text">Step 5</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <div class="future">
      <a href="/development/project/step6">
        <div id="unit" mix_id="" class="roadmap-icon">
          <svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-layout-wtf" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M5 1H1v8h4V1zM1 0a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v8a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h4a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V1a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H1zm13 2H9v5h5V2zM9 1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v5a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h5a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H9zM5 13H3v2h2v-2zm-2-1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v2a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h2a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H3zm12-1H9v2h6v-2zm-6-1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v2a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h6a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H9z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="/development/proforma/139/unit%20allocation/add" class="icon-text">
        Step 6
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="step">
    <div class="future">
      <a href="/development/project/step7">
        <div id="rates_id" class="roadmap-icon">
          <svg width="1.5em" height="1.5em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-card-list" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M14.5 3h-13a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v9a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h13a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5zm-13-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3.5v9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h13a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 14.5 2h-13z"
            ></path>
            <path
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              d="M5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7A.5.5 0 0 1 5 8zm0-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"
            ></path>
            <circle cx="3.5" cy="5.5" r=".5"></circle>
            <circle cx="3.5" cy="8" r=".5"></circle>
            <circle cx="3.5" cy="10.5" r=".5"></circle>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </a>

      <a href="/development/proforma/139/rates/add" class="icon-text">Step 7</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my website, this is what I get when removing the z-index of the past::after and keeping the z-index = -1 in future::before.  Note that when I inspect the element, the top, right, and z-index properties of .future::before are all greyed out with the hint i in front of it saying that "right has no effect on this element since it’s not a positioned element.

Try setting its position property to something other than static."  The position of the .future::before is absolute and its immediate parent's position is .step is relative.  How is it that the same browser displays the progress bar fine in one context and acts out in another context?  Here is the screen-shot of the problem I have:

[image]

Comment: Maybe there is some other code classing with this one in your website, which is not o Codepen.. can you share your website link...

Comment: code snippet is working fine

Comment: @aviboy2006 I know that the code snippet is working fine.  The problem is that I cannot figure out what's overriding the behavior.  Is it higher up parents overriding it?  What are the culprits?

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal The website is to be launched soon.  For now, it is not accessible

Comment: @EarlyCoder How can we help you with the working code you have provided!

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal Well, I know that z-index will not work if  some parent element has z-index set. So, I am looking for pointers as to what may be the cause. I can think of typo, which I checked already, but there may be some context settings by higher up parents that is causing this.

Comment: @EarlyCoder Try adding the CSS code at the end of the CSS File...